# Regular Expression to Replace Multiple Parts of a String (In Visual Studio 2012)

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Basically I am updating an old web app to be multi browser compliant.  All over the place the original programmers have used -

```
document.all.element
```

As I understand the ".all" is IE only, introduced in IE 4.  The standards compliant ".getElementById" function was introduced in IE 5.  I want to change instances of the above statement to -

```
document.getElementById("element")
```

How would I form this regular expression, specifically using Visual Studio's "Find and Replace" dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is an issue with me using Visual Studio 2012 RC but using braces failed to match to anything.

I ended up using the find expression -

```
document\.all\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
```

and the replacement

```
document.getElementById("$1")
```

The "$1" refers to the bracketed expression.

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: That could be the case, I am used to VS 2010 and you haven't mentioned you are on 2012.

Comment: I would have mentioned I was using 2012 but in this situation I didn't expect it would have made a difference.  Now I'm not sure what to do either edit my question to reflect the situation (and mark my answer as correct) or leave generic as your answer (and dasblinkenlight's) is correct for previous versions of visual studio.

Comment: I would not expect this to be different either, feel free to accept your answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio 2010 and earlier the regular expression syntax is following:

To tag an expression use `{ }`, to reference first tag for replacement use `\1`

In your case you need to find:

```
document\.all\.{[a-zA-Z0-9]+}
```

and replace with:

```
document.getElementById('\1')
```

In Visual Studio 2012 the regular expression syntax has changed to:

```
document\.all\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
document.getElementById('$1')
```

Comment: Isn't Visual Studio 2012's tag `( )` instead of `{ }`? That's older versions of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Search for

```
[.]all[.]{:i}
```

and replace with

```
.getElementById("\1")
```

The square brackets around dot `.` are to make sure it's not interpreted as meta-character (you can use `\.` instead). The `:i` is Visual Studio's symbol for an *identifier*.

The `\1` in the replacement string references the first *tagged* expression (i.e. the `{:i}` expression), so the identifier will be "pasted in" inside the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a regular expression.

Simply replace `document.all.element` by `document.getElementById` in the text replace dialog

Comment: Wouldn't work in this situation, I need to surround the "element" part with brackets and quotation marks.

Comment: Ok I get it. You document.all.elements is accessed by an index, this is not a function

Comment: Yeah, the `element` part of `document.all.element` is the elements name. so I wanted to keep that as it was the same as the elements id.